# Use property outside block: findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm using parse.com as database and I have a query to retrieve data. Although I see multiple threads about this, I can't figure out the solution to my code.

I run the query inside viewDidLoad of my tableViewController.

```
    PFQuery *exerciciosQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    [exerciciosQuery includeKey:@"exercicios"];
    [exerciciosQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    exerciciosArray = objects;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%@", objects);
}];
```

And I need to show the tableView according to the result of query:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    PFObject *exercicios = [exerciciosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[exercicios objectForKey:@"Title"]];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is, the property *exerciciosArray is null if not inside the block. Therefore, I'm not sure how to work around this to show the results of the query on my tableviewcells.

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information. Where and how is `exerciciosArray` declared? (i.e. is it a local variable or instance variable? Is it declared with `__block`?) When you say "exerciciosArray is null", is that just `nil` initially, or always? (I ask this because `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` sounds asynchronous, so the block will probably run after the table loads for the first time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `exerciciosArray = objects;` doesn't do what you think. You're assigning to a copy of exercisiosArray, not the original variable or property. That copy only exists inside the. You can use `__block` in the ivar declaration. That will tell the runtime to use the original variable in the block, and not create a copy.

**[EDIT] The above paragraph is incorrect. Ivars that are used inside the block are never copied, instead they're implicitly referenced through `self`, which is retained in the block. Adding the `__block` modifier to an ivar doesn't make any difference. Assigning to an ivar inside a block is OK. This is a somewhat subtle point of Objective-C that is not well documented.**

So you have two options:

1. Add `__block` to the declaration (if `exerciciosArray` is an iVar). **[EDIT] This is unnecessary. See the edit above.**
2. If `exerciciosArray` is a property, make `exerciciosArray` an `NSMutableArray`. Then, you can elements to it by doing `[exerciciosArray addObjectsFromArray:objects];`

Don't forget to do `[[exerciciosArray alloc] init]` where appropriate.

Comment: I've just tried both. My property declaration is like this: @property (strong, nonatomic) __block NSMutableArray *exerciciosArray; And I also tried to change it to NSMutableArray, but nothing worked. My tableview cells are still empty and when I run NSLog outside the block with exerciciosArray, it is null.

Comment: I guess NSLog outside the block gets executed before the block completes.

Comment: You can't have a __block property. If you want to use __block, you need to use an ivar.

Comment: NSMutableArray **should** work though, provided you do it right: init it **outside the block** prior to using it, and adding objects to it inside the block (but not assigning a new value to the variable).

Comment: In ViewDidLoad, outside the block, I have exerciciosArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];. And inside the block, also in viewDidLoad, I have [exerciciosArray addObjectsFromArray:objects]; when I log exerciciosArray outside the block, it is empty.

Comment: You want to log exerciciosArray after your block completes. If you print it too early, it will be empty.

Comment: how do I do that? Also, my tableview may also be getting the exerciciosArray empty, thats the reason it is not showing anything, right?

Comment: You correctly call `reloadData` at the end of the block. Can you confirm that `exerciciosQuery` has something in it by then? One other thing you may need to do is to ensure that `reloadData` is called on the main thread, like this: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self.tableView reloadData]; });`

Comment: Ok, so my code is like this: _exerciciosArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        NSLog(@"teste %@", _exerciciosArray);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self.tableView reloadData]; }); The array is ok when I NSLog there, but I still don't get anything in my tableview.

Comment: this is in cellForRowAtIndexPAth: PFObject *exercicios = [_exerciciosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[exercicios objectForKey:@"Title"]];
    
    
    return cell;

Comment: No, that's incorrect. Don't init _exerciciosArray inside the block, do it before you call the block! In the block, just add objects to it.

Comment: Ok, so just before calling the block, _exerciciosArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; and inside the block [_exerciciosArray addObjectsFromArray:objects];
Still no luck, I might be missing something, probably a little thing, but I can't see.

Comment: You're getting close. Does `_exerciciosArray` have objects at the end of the block? Do you call `reloadData` on the main thread, like I explained in an earlier comment?

Comment: yes, the NSLog inside the block shows populated array. And I guess the line dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self.tableView reloadData]; }); ensures it is reloading data on the main thread, right?

Comment: I think it worked, because I'm getting a totally different error: -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' from the lines PFObject *exercicios = [_exerciciosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[exercicios objectForKey:@"Title"]];

Comment: Yes and yes. The error you're getting now means _exerciciosArray is still empty when you try to use it. Make sure that `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns the correct value (even if it's 0).

Comment: @BlackRider: "If you want to use __block, you need to use an ivar." This is absolutely wrong. `__block` can only apply to local variables. Local variables are the only variables that can be captured in blocks. And `exerciciosArray` cannot be a local variable, because if it were, tne code would not compile. So in no case would `__block` be relevant here.

Comment: @newacct: Really? The `__block` modifier can be used with local variables, but also with ivars. I do it all the time. Proof: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW3 ("To override this behavior for a particular object variable, you can mark it with the __block storage type modifier."). For the OP, it does make sense to have exerciciosArray as an ivar.

Comment: @BlackRider: Well, you have been doing it wrong, and you have a wrong understanding of what `__block` is. "for a particular object variable": "object variable" = "local variable of object pointer type". See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html#the-block-storage-qualifier "In addition to the new Block type we also introduce a new storage qualifier, __block, for local variables." The whole point of `__block` is so that the variable is not captured by value. Instance variables are just access of `self->something`; the instance variable is not captured; `self` is captured.

Comment: @newacct: On the other hand, this page (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6) says: When a block is copied, it creates strong references to object variables used within the block. If you use a block within the implementation of a method: 

If you access an instance variable by reference, a strong reference is made to self; **If you access an instance variable by value, a strong reference is made to the variable.** Doesn't this mean that using an ivar in a block doesn't always retain self?

Comment: @BlackRider: They are using made-up terminology. If you see what they mean by "access an instance variable by value", what they are actually doing is assigning the instance variable to a local variable outside the block, and then accessing that local variable inside the block. The block has a strong reference to the object pointed to by this local variable (which is the same object as pointed to by the instance variable when the block is created).

Comment: @newacct: you are totally right, and I was wrong. I just tried it out, and every ivar behaves the same inside a block as a local __block variable. Which means that self must be retained. The __block modifier seems to have no effect on ivars (I wish there were a compiler warning for it). I'm going to edit my answer today to clarify this point. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: I couldn't delete my answer since it was already accepted, but I added a correction to it.